# Using selenium 3.0 with jdk1.8 and selenium webdriver beta version

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
List<WebElement> findElement = (List<WebElement>) driver.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
List<WebElement>  links = findElement;
System.out.println(links.size());
for (int i = 1; i<=links.size(); i=i+1)
{
    System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());
}
```

When i am trying to run this code, it is showing some issues as :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at Home_Screen.Home.main(Home.java:60)
```

I am running this for selenium webdriver 3.0 using google chrome

Comment: You forgot the `s` in `findElements`

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at Home_Screen.Home.main(Home.java:60)
```

As you are trying to store the output of `findElement(By.tagName("a")` (which returns a single *WebElement*) within a `List<WebElement>` so the *JVM* complains about **java.lang.ClassCastException** because an instance of *RemoteWebElement* can't be casted to *java.util.List*.

If you are trying to print the text within each `<a>` tag you can use the enhanced `for()` loop as per the following code block :

```
List<WebElement> find_all_a_elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for (WebElement ele:find_all_a_elements)
{
    System.out.println(ele.getText());
}
```